# Firebase unable to retrieve data using class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some fully functional lines of code retrieving each single data, but failed to retrieve them using class. Eg: These lines are working perfectly.

```
double value = (double) ds.child("player1score").getValue();
long value = (long) ds.child("point").getValue();
```

Yet, when retrieving using class, error occurs.
Here are the whole picture of my codes, not sure if it is sufficient for solving the question, feel free to let me know what else is needed, appreciate so much for any advice, thanks!

Round().class

```
public class Round {
public double player1score;
public double player2score;
public double player3score;
public double player4score;
public long point;

//Constructor
public Round(double player1score, double player2score, double player3score, double player4score, long point) {
    this.player1score = player1score;
    this.player2score = player2score;
    this.player3score = player3score;
    this.player4score = player4score;
    this.point = point;

//Below are All the getter and setter etc
}
```

My MainActivity.class.onCreate()

```
//Declare Variables
UserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = rootRef.child("user").child(UserId).child("gameInfo");
DatabaseReference gameRecordRef = rootRef.child("user").child(UserId).child("gameRecord");

String gameKey = "-LLyXhetqj9mj5fgh9bn";
```

Under onCreate():

```
gameRecordRef.child(gameKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ListView lv_history = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_history);

                ArrayList<Round> ResultList = new ArrayList<>();

                //This line is where the error pointed to
                Round round = (Round) ds.getValue(Round.class);

                ResultList.add(round);

                ivd_HistoryAdapter adapter = new ivd_HistoryAdapter(id_History.this, ResultList);
                lv_history.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
```

Firebase structure in text:

```
  "user": 
       "5xGKRXeHgThQy70lduPEp3mosTj1": 
             "gameRecord": 
                   "-LLyXhetqj9mj5fgh9bn": 
                        "player1score": 0.5,
                        "player2score": 0.5,
                        "player3score": 0.5,
                        "player4score": 0.5,
                        "point": 5
```

Logcat Error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class viwil.mahjongcal.Round does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>           at viwil.mahjongcal.id_History$1.onDataChange(id_History.java:51)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)

Error pointed to this line: (id_History.java:51)

```
    Round round = ds.getValue(Round.class);
```

Firebase screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ... does not define a no-argument constructor
```

Because your `Round` class does not define a `no-argument constructor`.

JavaBeans [require a no-argument constructor](https://coderanch.com/t/634008/java/java-bean-blank-arg-constructor) to be present in the model class.

In Java, when a class has no constructors at all, there is a default `no-argument constructor` automatically added by the Java compiler. The moment you define **any** constructor in the class, the default no-argument constructor goes away.

In your code, your `Round` class defines such a constructor that contains five arguments:

```
public Round(double player1score, double player2score, double player3score, double player4score, long point) {}
```

As long as this constructor is present and you don't define a `no-argument constructor`, that class will not have one.

To solve this, you either remove that constructor from the class, or manually add a `no-argument constructor` as shown below:

```
public Round() {}
```

When the Firebase Realtime database SDK deserializes objects that are coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use, to have this constructor, so it can use it to instantiate the object. Fields in the objects are set by using public setter methods or direct access to public members.

Your `Round` class dosen't have a public `no-arg constructor`, the SDK doesn't really know how to create an instance of it. So it is mandatory to have it.

Also please note that setters and getter are not required. Setters are always optional because if there is no setter for a JSON property, the Firebase client will set the value directly onto the field. A constructor-with-arguments is also not required. Both are idiomatic and there are good cases to have classes without them. If you make the fields public, the getters are optional too.

Comment: With all do respect, More like a copy-paste to me from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706656/4409113 but, hope this helps the OP.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท I think I've provided a few more details that can help the OP. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: For sure! Can't deny that. Hope that helps btw.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Also marked as duplicate. Thanks again! Cheers!

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Alex's answer truly helps and explains in detail, I appreciate so much for his help. Now the problem is solved perfectly!

Comment: @AlexMamo Appreciate so much for the help, solved perfectly and your answer provide a comprehensive background and explanation, thank you so much for that!

Comment: @WilsonKwun You're welcome, cheers!